# Streaming out of the smartphone

Tags: android, streaming, multimedia

I am inspecting the possibility of streaming Audio/Visual content OUT of the smartphone (Android OS).

I wonder, is it possible to use the built in Video/Audio recorder (Java class) to encode/compress the video, and get direct access to resulting buffers which can then be sent out of the device using sockets?

OR

Should I implement my own encoding logic using e.g. NDK & IPP?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The MediaRecorder class has a `setOutput(FileDescriptor)` method. You might try creating a LocalSocket and passing it's file descriptor. I'm not 100% sure if it would work though